# How do Babel transform JSX to valid JavaScript in realtime?

Tags: babeljs, jsx

I've seen this snippet on Next.js tutorials. I know that Babel transforms the JSX in ReactDOM.render function but I always assumed it was doing in Build Time. Since this snippet below works directly on the browser.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!-- Babel Script -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      const app = document.getElementById('app');
      ReactDOM.render(<h1>Develop. Preview. Ship. </h1>, app);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wonder why JavaScript doesn't throw an error when it encounters JSX directly, and how Babel prevents that?